# VB - How to start a for cycle after a specific string

Tags: vba, parsing

I'm developing a program and it uses `StreamReader` method.
Inside the code a have a `For` cycle but I only want it to be activated after a specific line appears.

This is for getting the n-th number on the following text layout.

*Specific string to start the cycle

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
   Nr.     a          b         c          d            Time 
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1    2.110     49.64     36.69     100.000          2
```

The code I made gets the numbers on the b column successfully, that's what I want.

```vb
For h = 1 To Len(line_c_2_1)    
    If Mid(line_c_2_1, h, 1) = " " Then
        I = I + 1

        If I = 3 Then
            line_c_2_1_out = Mid(line_c_2_1, h, 6)    

            If line_c_max <= line_c_2_1_out Then
                line_c_max = line_c_2_1_out
            Else
                line_c_max = line_c_max
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The output is some undesired number that appears before that specific string.

Comment: What is the undesired number that appears?

Comment: Are the numbers in fixed-width fields? Or are they separated by tab characters? What is the "specific line" - is it the second occurrence of a line of dashes?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to detect lines which consist of six strings which can be parsed as numbers?

Comment: For me it is quite unclear what you try to achieve and where the problem lies.

Comment: What is this line doing? `line_c_max = line_c_max`

Comment: This can't be both vba and vb.net. Which is it?

Comment: Are you checking alphabetical order here? `If line_c_max <= line_c_2_1_out Then`

Comment: I assume `line_c_2_1`,  `line_c_2_1_out`, and  `line_c_max` are strings. What are the initial values and where are they assigned?
I assume `I`  is an  Integer with initial value of zero. Yes?

Comment: @HereGoes  The undesired number is higher that the one I'm looking for. That's why it's undesired it's because is bigger, and doesn't account for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the numbers after that header 


[-------------------------------------------------------------
   Nr.     a          b         c          d            Time 
-------------------------------------------------------------], 

have all this layout. They are seperated by a tab

Comment: @AndrewMorton 

It would be necessary to also test if the six strings are numeric.

Comment: @Mary it's VBA my mistake. 
with the line "If line_c_max <= line_c_2_1_out Then"
I'm testing if the number is higher than the one on the previous cycle iteration

Comment: Don't know about VBA but in vb.net using Mid will return a string not a number. You cannot compare a string to a number.